# How to parameterize load test in sync?

Tags: soapui

I need to do load test using soapui open-source.

My test case steps are:

1. Test data (Groovy  script to create the sequential number from  1 to 1000000).
2. We service request ( use the sequential numbers that are created in step 1)
3. Groovy script ( increment value by 1 and redirect to step 1)

When I run the load test I am expecting to run sequentially. But it is not as expected!

From soapui it seems all are independent step. Everything is running continuously.. before getting response from web-service, the step 1 and step 3 runs multiple time. So the request is not in sequence..

How to resolve this?

Comment: First please go through with this link. https://blog.smartbear.com/soapui/parameterized-load-testing-using-soapui/

Comment: I have read that blog already. He has given how to read files and set it in to property. I already had things in step 1 and step 3 as it is in the blog.. but the actual fact is in each step individually runs multiple times. It is not actually carrying 1st row values not passed in the thread.. eg. When we start testing, Step 1 and step 3 runs 10 times before step 2 is completed. Then the webservice request takes 11th row instead of 2nd row for the 2nd hit.. hope you understand..